# Remove every second element from an array and rearange keys?

Tags: php, arrays

How should I remove every second element from an array like this (using nothing but the built in Array functions in PHP):

```
$array = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh');
```

And when I remove every second element, I should get:

```
$array = array('first', 'third', 'fifth', 'seventh');
```

Possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$array = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh');
foreach (range(1, count($array), 2) as $key) {
  unset($array[$key]);
}
$array = array_merge($array);
var_dump($array);
```

or

```
$array = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh');
$size = count($array);
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 2) {
  $result[] = $array[$i];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: you're the best! I will accept your answer in about 8-10 minutes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$array  = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh');
$keys   = range(0, count($array), 2);
$result = array_values(array_intersect_key($array, array_combine($keys, $keys)));
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
  if (($i % 2) == 0) unset ($array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: This will not rearrange the keys and (according the question) this will remove 0,2,4 , ..., but they should be kept. 1,3,5, ... should be removed. A minor "thing": You shouldn't use functions in a `for`-test-expression, because it get called in any iteration. Additional it will lead to unwanted behavior, because the size of the array changes (after the first `unset()` the size is not `$maxKey + 1` anymore).

Comment: @KingCrunch I just was giving him an example. Also I agree with using functions in a for-test-expression. But once again, this is just a school example how he should think in order to solve his problem.

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG, as KingCrunch stated, this will utterly mutilate an array. See my answer below.

Comment: if you "count" array each time in loop you will get wrong calculated value each "for" loop

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is a reverse-loop(along with the usual modulus)
For anyone looking for a copy and paste solution:

`for ($i = count($ar)-1; $i >= 0 ; $i--){
  if (($i % 2) == 0) unset ($ar[$i]);
}`

Comment: if you "count" array each time in loop you will get wrong calculated value