# PHP Regular Expression to break apart a Serialized String

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of the format:

`$15?1?2/:1$16E/:2$17?6?7/:6$19E/:7$3E/`

I want to use preg_split() to break this down into an array but I can't seem to get the regex right. Specifically I want to get an array with all the numerical values directly following each $.

So in this case:

```
[0] => 15
[1] => 16
[2] => 17
[3] => 19
[4] => 3
```

If someone could explain the regex to me that would produce this that would be amazing.

Comment: What regex did you try? Why you couldn't get the results be more specific on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Split vs. Match All**

Splitting and matching are two sides of the same coin. You don't even need to split: this returns the exact array you are looking for (see [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/uN6WR1)).

```
$regex = '~\$\K\d+~';
$count = preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 19
    [4] => 3
)
```

**Explanation**

- `\$` matches a `$`
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\d+` matches your digits

Hang tight for explanation. :)

Comment: Do you have an [advice on this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541489/crontab-intervals-preg-match) too, maybe?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Would love to help on your question, but not fully understanding the format. One example is not enough. @ me on your question if you add sample input.

Comment: Worked perfectly, easy to change to fit a variety of different strings now that *I think* I understand the format. Thank you so much zx81

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
$preg = preg_match_all("/\$(\d+)/", $input, $output);
print_r($output[1]);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5Rc

Answer (score 0):

Here is non-regular expression example:

```
$string = '$15?1?2/:1$16E/:2$17?6?7/:6$19E/:7$3E/';

$array = array_map( function( $item ) {
    return intval( $item );
}, array_filter( explode( '$', $string ) ) );
```

Idea is to explode the string by $ character, and to map that array and use the [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to get the integer value.

---

Here is [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) example that captures the delimiter:

```
$string = '$15?1?2/:1$16E/:2$17?6?7/:6$19E/:7$3';

$array = preg_split( '/(?<=\$)(\d+)(?=\D|$)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
/*
  (?<=\$)                  look behind to see if there is: '$'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (greedy))
  )                        end of \1
  (?=\D|$)                 look ahead to see if there is: non-digit (all but 0-9) OR the end of the string
*/
```

With a help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6519046/2352773) post, a interesting way to get every second value from resulting array.

```
$array = array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip( range( 1, count( $array ), 2 ) ) );
```